# resteasy-reactive-client does not delete Attr_ temp files for Multipart requests

Tags: netty, quarkus, resteasy, quarkus-rest-client

Hello dear quarkus community,

I am currently having issues with the deletion of temporary files when executing multipart http-requests with the reactive client.

I have a native quarkus application ("sender") running on a server that sends files to a REST-endpoint from another quarkus application ("collector") as a multipart request.

Here is the rest-client definition:

```
@RegisterRestClient(configKey = "collector-client")
@Path("/api/v1")
public interface CollectorRestClient {

    @POST
    @Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    @Path("/message/")
    String sendMessageFile(CollectorDto collectorDto);
}
```

The DTO looks like this:

```
public class CollectorDto {

    @FormParam("file")
    @PartType(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
    private File file;

    @FormParam("messageId")
    @PartType(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    private String messageId;

    @FormParam("providerId")
    @PartType(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    private String providerId;

    @FormParam("receivedDateTime")
    @PartType(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    private Instant receivedDateTime;

...
}
```

After some time, the host system of the sender was having issues with writing files, investigations showed that all inodes of the filesystem were used up. There were ~6 million temporary files created that were named e.g. Attr_7976485966177727808_571797615 and some bytes in size.

It looks like every part of my multipart request lead to the creation of a corresponding Attr_ file with the content of the file being the value of the part.

After some research, I found the netty class `DefaultHttpDataFactory` with the method `createAttribute` to be the place where these `DiskAttribute` instances are created.

It seems like the default quarkus configuration is to have the `useDisk` mode enabled and persist the multipart attributes. Also, the `deleteOnExit` flag on the attributes is set to false because of the default value in the `DefaultHttpDataFactory`.

Small detour: the deleteOnExit defaulting to false was introduced in march 2020 via https://github.com/netty/netty/commit/84ebf47515c93886e8e0302eb65effe86f152422 and the leaking seems to have been fixed in september 2020 via https://github.com/netty/netty/commit/95ce1b95ea5679f826cdefcbaabb3b7c2d596100 so I am not sure if the default is still required to be off.

Netty suggests, that the release of the HttpData should be done manually after the request is finished:

```
for (InterfaceHttpData httpData: decoder.getBodyHttpDatas()) {
  httpData.release();
  factory.removeHttpDataFromClean(request, httpData);
}
factory.cleanAllHttpData();
decoder.destroy();
```

however, I only call the `@Post` method on the interface with `@RegisterRestClient` so I don't know how to get access to the decoder and the factory here.

**Expectation:**
All temporary files that were created in the context of a http-request should be deleted once the request in finished (e.g. the response has been deserialized).

**Current behaviour:**
Attributes of the multipart request are persisted as temporary files and are not cleaned up automatically. A manual cleanup is not possible due to missing access to the HttpDataFactory and the Decoder.

**Problems:**
I have looked for some way to configure the netty `useDisk` and `deleteOnExit` behaviour via config but could not find fitting properties.

I tried to trigger the cleanup of the DiskAttributes manually but found no easy way to get access to the netty object instances that hold the required data.

**Versions in use:**

| lib | version |
| --- | --- |
| quarkus | 2.16.6-Final |
| resteasy-reactive-client | 2.16.6-Final |
| netty | 4.1.86.Final |

Comment: This sounds like a bug. Can you please open an issue at https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues including a sample project that exhibits the behavior you mention?

Comment: yes, I will do so. Thank you for the feedback.

Comment: I created a sample project and a github issue: https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/33986